# What is the bitstream format of 25-bit ARGB1888?

Tags: argb

I am working on RGB color formats and I came across the RGB formats as listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#top). I was just wondering what will be the 25-bit ARGB1888 format bit-stream look like.
Will it be

```
AUUUUUUU RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB
```

or

```
UUUUUUUA RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB
```

where A = Alpha bit, U = unused bit, R = Red Color, G = Green Color, B = Blue Color.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: I believe the alpha channel is also a full 8 bits, making it `AAAAAAAA RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB`.  Which octet would be first in a bitstream would depend on the endian-ness.

Comment: Hi! Thank You Joe for the reply. But if you could refer to the link it says 25-bit ARGB1888 but not 32-bit. Had it been 32-bit what you say is correct.